# Is there way to print IPv6 address selection precedence in command line?

Tags: networking, ip-address

I can print address' label via `ip addrlabel` and override label and precedence in `/etc/gai.conf`, but how to print current precedence in command line?

In https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-addrlabel.8.html, it says

> Precedence is managed by userspace, and only the label itself is stored in the kernel.

but how to print that?

In windows, I can simply type:

```
$ netsh int ipv6 show prefixpolicies
Querying active state...

Precedence  Label  Prefix
----------  -----  --------------------------------
        50      0  ::1/128
        40      1  ::/0
        30      2  2002::/16
        20      3  ::/96
        10      4  ::ffff:0:0/96
         5      5  2001::/32
```

How to do the same thing in Ubuntu?

Thanks.

Comment: What would you use it for exactly ? for applications (i.e. destination address selection) `cat /etc/gai.conf` _is_ in fact how you'd print that (provided that your Linux is using glibc), but note that it is not used by `ip addrlabel` (i.e. source address selection)

Comment: @LL3 "But note that it is not used by ip addrlabel (i.e. source address selection)". In RFC 3484 (now RFC 6724), it seems that source address selection and destination address selection use the same Policy Table. Do you mean that Linux uses different Policy Table for source address selection and destination address selection?

Comment: @LL3 "cat /etc/gai.conf is in fact how you'd print that.." There is nothing in `/etc/gai.conf` except comments. Do you mean that these comments are exactly the Default Policy Table in RFC 6724?

Comment: actually I was just noting that `ip addrlabel` and `gai.conf` are unrelated and was wondering what you need to achieve. However, 1) AFAIK `ip addrlabel` is only used for complying to "Rule 6" of the RFC in source selection, the Linux kernel to date does not offer a sysadmin maintainable preference list for that. 2) a missing or comment-only `gai.conf` uses the policy table described in those comments, which equals the default as per the rfc AFAICT

Comment: @LL3 Thanks. "wondering what you need to achieve" Just want to print rfc policy table, because in general if some attribute can be edited, it can be printed too. (I searched Google, but only results for Windows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't print the current address precedence on Linux, unfortunately.

The default is hardcoded in glibc², possibly reflected by the comments in `/etc/gai.conf`, and possibly successfully overwritten with that same file.

(By the way: source address selection is done by the kernel, destination address selection by glibc. -- And *the kernel* does indeed have an interface to list *its current share* of that RFC 3484/6724 table.)

---

² Look for `default_precedence` in the [source code](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nss/getaddrinfo.c;hb=b881f1efcd1b30c2afab3599b41ce9cd4864c823#l1368).